# Cambiar simbolo '\' a simbolo '/' en una cadena de python

Tags: python, string

Estoy intentando crear un programa que cambia el símbolo `'\'` por el símbolo `'/'` de una ruta de directorio para después crear una carpeta en esa ruta, el problema es cuando intento cambiarlo me da el siguiente error :

> '*Parsing failed: 'EOL while scanning string literal*'.

He estado investigando por diferentes páginas web pero todavía no he encontrado a nadie con el mismo error y la verdad es que esto se me hace muy extraño.

El primer código que intente es este:

```
import os

ruta_objetivo = input('Escriba la ruta objetivo de forma absolta: ')  
ruta_objetivo = ruta_objetivo.replace('\', '/' )  
print(ruta_objetivo)  

"""  
os.system(f'cd "{ruta_objetivo}"')  
os.system('mkdir Esto_Es_Una_Prueba')  
"""
```

Pero este código ni siquiera llega al print,tambien he probado esto:

```
import os

ruta_objetivo = input('Escriba la ruta objetivo de forma absolta: ')  
ruta_objetivo = ruta_objetivo.replace(r'\', r'/' )  
print(ruta_objetivo)  

"""  
os.system(f'cd "{ruta_objetivo}"')  
os.system('mkdir Esto_Es_Una_Prueba')  
"""
```

Pero sigue dando el mismo error, ¿Alguien me puede ayudar en cómo solucionar esto?

Comment: El primer caso te funciona, solo que debes escapar la barra para que la detecte como string y no te de error: `ruta_objetivo = ruta_objetivo.replace('\\', '/' )`

Comment: La barra invertida `'\'` es el caracter de escape en `Python` por eso debes poner dos tal como menciona @FranciscoJavier, para que el intérprete entienda que deseas buscar ese símbolo [Lectura recomendada](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/secuencias-de-escape-en-python/)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta @FranciscoJavier , podrías ponerlo como una respuesta para poder marcar el post como cerrado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como en cualquier otro lenguaje de programación, en `Python` existen caracteres especiales, los cuales, como es el caso de las comillas simples `'` o dobles `"`, por ejemplo, pueden servir para delimitar su contenido como una cadena. Pero ¿qué ocurre si queremos incluir esos caracteres dentro de dicha cadena? `

`"Mi cadena entre comillas dobles con una "comilla doble"`

> Se producirá un error...

Para poder emplear dichos caracteres especiales sin que `Python` los vea como una `instrucción`, debemos escaparlos, y para ello se usa precisamente la barra invertida `\`, que debe anteponerse para ello al carácter a escapar.

Por lo tanto, por ejemplo, el primer caso de los que has propuesto funcionará con la simple inclusión de la barra invertida dos veces seguidas, escapándose a sí misma, puesto que es un carácter especial más. Si no, de no hacerlo así, estarías escapando la comilla simple que la sigue...

```
import os

ruta_objetivo = input('Escriba la ruta objetivo de forma absolta: ')  
ruta_objetivo = ruta_objetivo.replace('\\', '/' )  
print(ruta_objetivo)
```